# Struggling with while loop in this algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program to calculate euclidean distance and then display the lines based, with the below code:

```js
function discreteFrechet(X, Y) {
  var M = X.length;
  var N = Y.length;
  var S = [
    [],
    []
  ];
  var backpointers = [
    [],
    []
  ];
  var backpaths = [];
  var idx;
  var path = [];
  var paths;
  var back = [
    [],
    []
  ];


  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {

      S[i][j] = 0;
      backpointers[i][j] = 0;
    }
  } /* populates S array */
  /*sanity check*/
  S[0, 0] = euclidian(X, Y, 0, 0);
  opt1 = [-1, 0];
  opt2 = [0, -1];
  opt3 = [-1, -1];

  backpaths.push(opt1);
  backpaths.push(opt2);
  backpaths.push(opt3);
  /*backpaths populated*/

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      options = [];
      if (i != 0 || j != 0) {

        if (i > 0) {
          options[0] = S[i - 1, j];
        }
        if (j > 0) {
          options[1] = S[i - 1, j];
        }
        if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
          options[2] = S[i - 1, j];
        }

        idx = Math.min(options);
        backpointers[i][j] = idx;

        S[i][j] = Math.max(options[idx], euclidian(X, Y, i, j));
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(S);
  paths = [
    [M - 1, N - 1]
  ];
  path = [
    [],
    []
  ];
  path.push(paths);
  //Create "path"
  i = M - 1;
  j = N - 1;
  count = 0;
  while ((path[path.length - 1][0] != 0) || (path[0][path[1].length - 1] != 0)) {
    back[0][1] = backpaths[backpointers[i], [j]];
    i += back[0];
    j += back[1];
    path.push([i, j]);
    if (count > 1000) {
      console.log("too many loops");
      break;
    }
    count += 1;
  }
  path.push([0, 0]);
  path.reverse();
  //returns bottleneck and the path
}
```

As I am testing, I am running into a problem with an infinite while loop (hence the break statement) any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! The goal is to append indicies into the path element, such that I can then take those path indicies and the bottleneck and use them to plot with d3.

Comment: do you have some data? do you declare the variables somwhere?

Comment: yea this code is pretty large, paths is populated correctly, and path is instanciated as a 2d array. this whole thing is based on allowing the user to draw points in the browser (which works) and calculate euclidean distance based on those points

Comment: Several problems here: `backpointers[i,j]` is not the way to access a 2D array. Should probably be `backpointers[i][j]`, but we don't know what it is. `[[M-1],[N-1]]` looks wrong too. Should probably be `[[M-1,N-1]]`, but we don't know what `M` or `N` is. `[[],[]]` is probably also not what you want. Probably just `[]`.

Comment: Yea that tracks, i am translating this from python so its a little tricky in my brain to process, thanks!

Comment: Probably `back[0][1] = ` is also wrong. Guessing that `back` is a 1d array, so then this cannot work. Guessing you want to assign to `back[0]` and `back[1]` separately (or with destructuring), but without knowing what the intention is or what `backpaths` is, I don't see how we can help you. This is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Yea stack overflow yelled at me for posting the whole code, let me see what i can do rq

Comment: There is the whole method, the eculidian calls are to a separate method that just runs the euclidean calculation